# Prove: If $p$ is prime and $p \mid a_1a_2\dots a_n$, then $p \mid a_i$ for $i\in\{1, \dots, n\}$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Euclid's lemma: If $p\mid ab$, then $p\mid a$ or $p\mid b$.

Prove: If $p$ is prime and $p \mid a_1a_2\dots a_n$, then $p \mid a_i$ for some $i = 1, 2, \dots, n$.

Proof by Induction:

P(1): From $p\in\mathbb{P}$ and $p\mid a_1$ it follows that:
\begin{equation*}
p \mid a_i,
\end{equation*}
for $i = 1$. P(1) is true.

P(2): If $p\in\mathbb{P}$ and $p\mid a_1a_2$ it follows from the lemma that if $p \nmid a_1$, then:
\begin{equation*}
p \mid a_2,
\end{equation*}
so
\begin{equation*}
p \mid a_i
\end{equation*}
for some $i = 1, 2$.

On the other hand, if $p\mid a_1$, then the same conclusion is reached. P(2) is true.

Now assume P(k) inductively:
\begin{equation*}
p \mid a_1a_2\dots a_k \rightarrow p \mid a_i
\end{equation*}
for some $i = 1, 2, \dots, k$.

P(k+1) is also true because from $p \mid (a_1a_2\dots a_k)a_{k+1}$ two cases arise:

Case I: $p\nmid a_1\dots a_k$.

Using Euclid's lemma it follows that if $p\nmid a_1\dots a_k$, then:
\begin{equation*}
p\mid a_{k+1}
\end{equation*}
and thus:
\begin{equation*}
p\mid a_i,
\end{equation*}
for some $i = 1, 2, \dots, k+1$.

Case II: $p\mid a_1\dots a_k$.

By the inductive hypothesis, the conclusion may be reached:
\begin{equation*}
p \mid a_i,
\end{equation*}
for some $i = 1, 2, \dots,k, k+1$.

Comment: Do you mean $p|a_i$ for "some" $i=1,2,\dots n$?

Comment: @W. Wongcharoenbhorn, yea that is what I mean. I just decided to wrap everything in a set because that's how the problem was presented.

Comment: W. Wongcharoenbhorn I guess I could just as easily have broken it up into the cases $p\mid a_1\dots a_k$ and $p\nmid a_1\dots a_k$.

Comment: As stated, the proposition is false. It is true that if $p\mid a_1\cdots a_n$ then $p$ divides at least one of $a_1,\ldots,a_n.$ But the proposition you stated says $p$ divides ALL of $a_1,\ldots,a_n,$ and that is false. It is very easy to find lots of counterexamples to that.

Comment: So should I change it to "for some i = 1, 2, ..., n"? You're saying that I asked the wrong question?

Comment: @xhsbm Let me know if I have successfully addressed your questions/concerns.

Comment: The argument is correct but longer than it needs to be. You are essentially repeating the gcd-based proof of $P(2)$ in your inductive step. Instead you should invoke that result by name (either separate it out as a Lemma, or use strong/complete induction, as in the linked dupe).

Comment: There is no need to specially handle $P(3)$ and $P(4)$ since they are handled by your inductive step.

Comment: Please don't change the proof in your question after there are already comments and answer(s) discussing the original proof, since this makes the question inconsistent with these prior comments and answers. Instead you should append an "Edit: ..." if you wish to say more.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your argument written more concisely/clearly:

For all arguments for $n=1$ case is trivial.

If $p \mid a_1\cdots a_n \implies p \mid a_{i}$ for some $n$ then suppose $ p \mid a_1\cdots a_na_{n+1}=(a_{1}\cdot\cdot\cdot a_{n})a_{n+1}$

By the $n=2$ case we must have that $p$ divides atleast one of them.

Then if $p \mid (a_1\cdots a_n)$ we are done by the inductive hypothesis, and if $p \nmid (a_1\cdots a_n)$,  $p \mid a_{n+1}$, and the $i$ that satisfies the implication is $n+1$.

Your proof does not use the inductive hypothesis because you are using using an additional $\gcd$ result based on properties of primes. This not necessary as you may use the $n=2$ case of the theorem known as Euclid's lemma. Although, it is a similar result.

The issue is, you are having to note basic results and insights when you could have just proven the $n=2$ case and done a standard induction.

Below are my initial proofs:

One proof is to use strong induction on $n$ and once again Euclid's lemma for the $n=2$ case.

Then $p\mid a_1\cdots a_n \implies p\mid(a_1\cdots a_{n-1})a_n$. If $p \nmid a_n, $then $p\mid(a_1\cdots a_{n-1})$.

You may fill in the details, but by repeating this process of moving the paranthesis inductively, one finds that $p\mid a_i$ for some $i$.

Also, consider the proof where we start with $a_{1}\cdot\cdot\cdot a_{n}=pk$ for some integer $k$.

Then by the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic, $p$ must be in the prime expansion of the $LHS$, and hence in the prime expansion of at least one of the $a_{i}$'s.

Comment: So my proof is wrong?

Comment: No, actually, what you had in mind is better, just written much longer than necessary. I will edit my answer.

Comment: Note that if you are using the n=2 case in your induction step,then you are really using the n=2 case as the base case of the induction. The n=1 case will still need to be proved separately, but calling that the base case would not be correct as it is not used to start the induction process.

Comment: I understand how you did it. With the changes I made, is what I wrote above an acceptable solution?

Comment: Yes, it is correct just very long winded(you must work on cutting the length down)...However at the line,  "Using this it follows that:", you accidentally leave out a very important part of the induction, where you place the parentheses to separate the terms and the result becomes clear.

Comment: @Derek Luna Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: @xhsbm I encourage you to start upvoting/accepting answers to your many questions, so such questions may leave the unanswered category.

Comment: @Derek Luna, what do you mean I have to "place parentheses" in the inductive step? I rewrote the problem since last time.

Comment: @xhsbm It looks like it was fixed!